# Dependency Injection with Constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor, inversion-of-control, constructor-injection

I have two Classes. Student and SMSSenderMessage. where Student depend to SMSSenderMessage and SMSSenderMessage is depended to Student. Student and SMSSenderMessage has just one Constructor.
I want to use constructor injection for this two classes.

```
    public interface IPerson
    {
        string GetName();
    }

    public interface ISenderMessage
    {
        void Send(string text);
    }

    public class Student : IPerson
    {
        private ISenderMessage S;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Student(ISenderMessage s)
        {
            this.S = s;
        }
        public void DoSomeThing()
        {
            //...Some Thing
            S.Send("Hello");
        }

        public string GetName()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }
    public class SMSSenderMessage : ISenderMessage
    {
        IPerson P;
        public SMSSenderMessage(IPerson p)
        {
            P = p;
        }
        public void Send(string text)
        {
            string message = text + " " + P.GetName();

            //Send SMS: message
        }
    }
```

now. how create instance from Student and SMSSenderMessage?

Comment: Your classes contain a cyclic dependency and can, therefore, not be created. You should try to break the cycle. Take a look, for instance, at the section [6.3 Fixing cyclic Dependencies](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/234) from the book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl).

Comment: To make a shortcut: Why don't you pass `Person` to `Send` method instead of having a field? I don't know if that's due to simplification in the example but the _class_ SMSSenderMessage does not seem to need `Person` outside that method. In fact you could even just pass another string `name`... Is there a technical reason that `Send` builds the message text at all? Why not just pass the complete message and leave construction up to the caller?

Comment: this is not a real world sample

Comment: Well, obviously you thought it would sufficiently represent your real world code. We can base our suggestions only on what we get from the question.

Comment: @user3868142 could you please clarify a question title a bit. It's better to have something like "Dependency Injection with constructor when classes depend on each other"

Answer (score 6):

You have a cyclic dependency, so these classes cannot be created.

Let's say you have *class A*, which depends on *class B*, which depends on *class A*. Then, to create *class A*, you should firstly create *class B*, but to create *class B*, you should firstly create *class A*. So it's just impossible to create neither *class A* neither *class B*.

When you have a cyclic dependency, it means that you have some problem with your design. You should try to redesign your solution.

In your case, a design mistake is pretty obvious. You have a `SMSSender` which gets `IPerson` as a dependency to use a person's name when sending a message. But try to imagine how you could use this SMS sender in the future. If you need to send information with the order number, what would you do? Pass `Order` as a parameter into the `SMSSender` constructor? You shouldn't do that.

The answer is that your `SMSSender` shouldn't know anything about the kind of information it's sending. It should just get a message text and send it. So, you should remove `IPerson` dependency from `SMSSender`.

Comment: It's even questionable if `Student` needs a class field of `SMSSenderMessage`. It _may_ never be used. I'd just create one with `new` inside `DoSomething`. But that may be due to simplification of the example.

Answer (score 1):

As a couple of other people have suggested in comments, you have created a cyclic dependency - where each class has dependency on the other. Think of it like the infamous "Chicken and Egg" scenario! You can't instantiate one object without first instantiating the other.

However, the simplest way to separate concerns is to pass the IPerson object to the Send method.

You do ***not*** really want to pass the person into the SMSMessageConstructor because then you would have to create a new instance of SMSMessageConstructor for *every* different target person! Instead, pass IPerson within the Send method.

Also, I have suggested changing the `GetName()` method to a property, and advise that you pass the Name and PhoneNumber parameters into the Person *constructor* with **readonly** getter methods for immutability.

See updated code below:

```
    public interface IPerson
    {
        string Name { get; }
        string PhoneNumber { get; }
    }

    public interface ISenderMessage
    {
        void Send(IPerson person, string message);
    }

    public class Student : IPerson
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; }

        public Student(string name, string phoneNumber)
        {
            Name = name;
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }
    }

    public class SMSSenderMessage : ISenderMessage
    {
        public SMSSenderMessage() { }

        public void Send(IPerson person, string message)
        {
            // Access property of person, person.PhoneNumber
            // Optionally access name property of person, person.Name   
            // Send SMS: implement message logic.
        }
    }
```

Finally, a slight alternative using the newer Expression-bodied member + Tuple syntax for methods/constructors, see below (it's slightly shorter and rather neat!):

```
    public interface IPerson
    {
        string Name { get; }
        string PhoneNumber { get; }
    }

    public interface ISenderMessage
    {
        void Send(IPerson person, string message);
    }

    public class Student : IPerson
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; }

        public Student(string name, string phoneNumber) => (Name, PhoneNumber) = (name, phoneNumber);

    public class SMSSenderMessage : ISenderMessage
    {
        public SMSSenderMessage() { }

        public void Send(IPerson person, string message) => // Implement send message logic.
    }
```